# Object completely losing orientation using Lerp

Tags: unity, c#

So, I am making a 2d board game with unity.
Basically, two characters are moving on the board when clicking a spot on the board.
Since it's a static one frame 2d game, I put all of my game objects children of the canvas.
All the positions seems to be aligned, in the canvas itself everything is in place, also when I am debugging I notice that both of the positions, the local position and the target position are correct, so when I'm not using lerp and just setting the character position to the target position, it works perfect.

*Lerp/Smooth damp are working perfect outside the canvas*
I think it's something related to the update function, as it's updating false positions, but that's all I can guess...
This is the Update function of the Player class:

```
        private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (moveTowards == true)
    {
        velocity = Vector3.zero;
        this.transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(this.transform.localPosition, targetSpotPosition, ref velocity, .08f);
    }

    if (this.transform.position == targetSpotPosition)
    {
        moveTowards = false;
    }
}
```

moveTowards set to true when clicking a spot.

```
    public void movePlayerTo(Spots moveHere)
{
    moveTowards = true;
    moveHere.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(moveHere.transform.position);
    targetSpotPosition = moveHere.transform.position;
    //targetSpotPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(targetSpotPosition);
}
```

moveHere is the spot's position, there's no problem there.

I set my canvas to camera space render mode, and of course scale with screen size. Before putting everything in the canvas, it worked perfectley.

HELP PLEASE.
Thanks in advance,

Omer

Comment: It sounds like you have a bug in your code. If you'd like help debugging your code, you should **edit your question** to include a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of the problem (all code and scene setup instructions we'd need to reproduce a sample of the problem in a new, empty project). It would also help to include screenshots so we can see how the behaviour you're getting now differs from what you expect.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question and added the code. Regarding screenshots, I'm not sure it will be very helpful since this behavior is more of an update issue and changes every frame, maybe a video could have been beneficial. Anyway, do you see something in the code that may cause that? I am mentioning again, that before I put the game objects children of the canvas, it worked great. Thanks so much.

Comment: Your code makes reference to world space, which is completely inappropriate for objects in a screen space camera canvas. I'd recommend either dropping the canvas and working in world space, or changing to use UI-based positioning with RectTransforms, anchoredPositions, [RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle.html), etc. [We have some existing Q&A about this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/185046/39518).

Comment: Thank you so much. If I'm dropping the canvas, how shall I make my game resolution dynamic to fit different screen sizes?..

Comment: That sounds like a different question. You can edit your post to ask that instead or post a new question, showing a screenshot of what your game looks like on your primary target resolution, and a mock-up or detailed descriptions of what should change on different resolutions.

Comment: Let me know if you'd still like help with this code, or if you intend to replace it entirely in an edit. There are several fundamental problems beyond the world-space/camera-space mismatch, including resetting velocity to zero every step when trying to use SmoothDamp, assigning a localPosition to a position (two different coordinate spaces), passing a world position to ScreenToWorldPoint (which as its name suggests, expects a screen position)... Just about every line here is seriously flawed in one way or another.

Comment: Although there isn't a whole lot of info to go off of. If I had to guess it might be some to do with parenting and scaling. You might want to try your test again with the canvas not scaled to match the screen.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. Well, I understood your point and I did drop the canvas. I have some background in coding, but not on Unity platform, it can get confusing at the beginning. I though that in 2D, when we have a static top-shot camera, all the game objects most be children of the canvas, to fit multiple resolutions, obviously, I was wrong. I just moved everything (excluding UI elements) to world space, and added some scripts to the camera so it will adjust the resolution to the screen size of the device it's running on. Thank you so much!